# Joomla! 1.7 trying to embed an extension in a module

Tags: html, joomla

I'm not sure if this is really the best method, but I've only been working with joomla for two days so am very inexperienced.

Basically I have an html container in my template that holds a carousel extension and a set of images. The container has a blue background in contract to the white of the rest of the website.

I basically want to toggle that container with the extension on different pages. Here's my code:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="photos">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="carousel" />
    </div>
    <div id="social_media">
        <a id="success" href="#">Read about our success stories</a>
        <a id="partner" href="#">Be a partner</a>
        <a id="facebook" href="#">Join us on Facebook</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is make this entire chunk of code into a Custom HTML module that only display on certain pages.

I've attempted to do this but the extension for the carousel doesn't show up, nor the jdoc:include part. I'm guessing this is because Joomlas text editor doesn't interpret jdoc:includes the same way the joomla engine does.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Hi Tom - basically you're right the custom HTML module doesn't get processed for PHP.
Which which version of Joomla?

Comment: why do you want to create a new module position, do you want to be able to manage your slides in the backend?

Comment: No it's just so that I only have the whole box on one page only without having to do a separate template. Also its 1.7, as the title says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to load a module within an article (or a Custom HTML module) you want to use the loadposition command.  Here is what it would look like in your case:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="photos">
            {loadposition carousel}
    </div>
    <div id="social_media">
        <a id="success" href="#">Read about our success stories</a>
        <a id="partner" href="#">Be a partner</a>
        <a id="facebook" href="#">Join us on Facebook</a>
    </div>
</div>
```